# Draw an image on web site at the end of the script

Tags: php, html, css, image, web

I have a little problem. At the end of my R script I create an image .png as output. I wanna show this image on my website but sometimes it is drawn, sometimes it is not drawn. I don't understand how it is possible. I`ll put my code:

I insert the image in a div with this features:

```
#diagramm {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-color: #6495ED;
    width: 820px;
    height: 370px;
    margin: 2px auto;
    margin-top: 2em;
    background-image: url("/home/daniele/public_html/appweb2013/venn_final/fungo_final.png");
}
```

Where is the mistake? Can I use a better method?

Answer (score 0):

This is CSS, it only puts specific design rules for an element that has the id diagramm.

So what you've posted is not code so to speak.

In what way do you generate the output? When? what does the user do to generate it etc. 
Do you have any javascript or html code you can show?